# Include related model in an hasOne relation

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two models: `Account` and `Customer` both having an email address. 
An `Account` can exist without a `Customer` and a `Customer` can exist without an `Account`.
However, an `Account` should return the related `Customer` record if this exists.
I was thinking about doing this by creating a `hasOne` relation on the `Account` using the unique identifier available in both records (the email address) as foreignKey.
Unfortunately this is not working.
These are my models:

**Account**

```
...
"properties": {
  "username": {
    "type": [
      "string"
    ]
  },
  "email": {
    "type": "string"
  }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {
  "customer": {
    "type": "hasOne",
    "model": "Customer",
    "foreignKey": "email"
  }
}
...
```

**Customer**

```
...
"properties": {
  "name": {
    "type": [
      "string"
    ]
  },
  "email": {
    "type": "string"
  }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {}
...
```

By calling `/api/account?filter={"include": ["customer"]}` I don't get any additional information.
I don't understand if the problem is the foreignKey or the relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [afterRemote hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) to do the marshaling just before returning the requested instance.

However this won't be automatic, i.e. you still need to provide some sort of id to link the two instances together. In your case, if the email is such an id, then you would just search for a Customer instance with the same email as the Account instance.

The advantage is that you don't need to provide any extra filters or anything else to your query.

e.g.

```
Account.afterRemote('find', function(ctx, modelInstance, next) {
    // Here you can check if the Account instance has a Customer instance 
    // via a regular find or findById, and if you do find the related instance
    // you can add the data to ctx.result, which is the object that will be returned. 

    Customer.find({where:{email: modelInstance.email}}, addCustomerDetails); 

    function addCustomerDetails(err, linkedCustomer) {
        // Add the Customer to the Account instance here
        ctx.result.customer = linkedCustomer;
        next();
    }
});
```

And of course, you can do the same in the Customer afterRemote hook, but instead searching for the linked Account instance email.

Comment: Would you considering accepting the answer? or is something still missing we can help you out with?

Comment: At the moment, this is the best answer. I was wondering if there could be a different one involving the `hasOne` relationship, but I guess the answer is "no".

Comment: Found an answer here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976305
Replace "hasOne" relation with "belongsTo"

Answer (score 1):

Your models are defined well.

Be sure you have customer instance with existed email in db.

And the correct for of rest api calls is : `/api/account?filter[include]=customer`

**UPDATE**

Loopback overwrite the type of `email` because of the relation. `hasOne` relation should be setup over `id` foreign key not any other fields.

So if you want to fix the problem, you need to add below to properties section of `account` definition :

```
"id": false,
 "email": {
   "type": "string",
   "id": true
 }
```

Comment: I tried both syntax, but still nothing. I'm not using any database at the moment. Anything is in memory and both instances have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreignKey` field is just an alias for the relation. Having an `email` property and setting `email` as `foreignKey` does not create any sort of link between the two.

Then, it's simply a matter of using the REST API to instanciate the models, setup the relation and fetch the data

### create an account

```
POST api/accounts/ 
{
  "email": "account@bar.com"
}
```

### create a related customer

```
POST api/accounts/1/foreignKey
{
  "email": "customer@bar.com"
}
```

### Fetch the accound and include the related customer

```
GET api/accounts/1?filter[include]=foreignKey
```

Comment: I see your point, but this mean I cannot have a relationship automatically created by simply having the same value in both records, right?

Comment: You cannot create a Looback relationship automatically that way. I understand better what you're trying to achieve, let me formulate another answer

Comment: @Acapulco answer is pretty much what I was going for. Most likely the accepted answer