# Issue with including related Model in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two Models Customer and UserProviders

In Customer.json, have the following relation

```
"relations": {
    "userProviders": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "UserProviders",
      "foreignKey": "userId",
      "options": {
        "disableInclude": true,
        "http": {
          "path": "providers"
        },
        "hidden": [
          "id",
          "providersCount"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

UserProviders.json

```
{
  "name": "UserProviders",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "userId": {
      "type": "objectId",
      "required": true,
      "index": {
        "unique": true
      }
    },
    "providers": {
      "type": [
        "any"
      ],
      "default": []
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

This is how I tried to query the models in another Model say ModelB.

```
let users = ModelB.app.models.Customer;
let UserProvider = ModelB.app.models.UserProviders;

let userData = await users.findOne({
            where: {
            patientId: patientId
          },
            include: {
              relation: 'userProviders',
              scope: {
                fields: ['providers']
              }
            }
    });
```

Did a deep research on it. Checked the [Joining two models in loopback using include filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899067/joining-two-models-in-loopback-using-include-filter) result , but still not able to fix that.

Working on this for a couple of days. But still I am not getting the providers field included in userData. Any help would be really appreciated.
How can i include the related model field? Please correct me if i am wrong.